# How global functions on swift are compiled/dispatched?

Tags: swift, compiler-construction, global, dispatch

I have seen other questions related to this topic but any of them has an explanation on how the compiler deal with these functions and how they are dispatched, if they behave like a `inline` function or what?

Basically I would like to know the performance difference between using global functions and class/static functions.

**Note:** I am not asking if it is a good practice or not, just which option has better performance.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but they're statically dispatched. Vtable/dynamic dispatch wouldn't make sense, because global functions don't have multiple implementations that need to be chosen from by the runtime. Inlining is commonly done, but isn't guaranteed.

Comment: See: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0193-cross-module-inlining-and-specialization.md

Comment: @Alexander you right, there is no sense for dynamic dispatch. So we can assume that they will be dispatched statically. So basically the performance will be the same as a class/static function, with the difference of the name spacing.

Comment: As static functions, yes. But not the same as class methods, which require dynamic dispatch in non-final classes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `static`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://github.com/vandadnp/swift-weekly/blob/master/issue11/README.md#inline), the default is to inline them sometimes. Compilers have gotten pretty good at figuring out when something can be optimized but if you want to prevent or force an inline, you can do it with the `@inline` attribute.

I'm not sure how this affects performance, but if I had to guess I'd say the `global` function might be slightly faster than the `class` function unless the class is marked as `final` or the function is marked `static`.

Comment: As @Alexander explain on a comment, they might be statically dispatched (since there is no sense for dynamic dispatch) so the performance might be the same, or as you said, a slightly faster.

Comment: @rgkobashi you're right, I meant to say it was faster than a `class` function, which can be overridden.